# merging lines with matching first and second column value

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with data and I'm looking to achieve it by awk. How can I do this?

```
111,10.1.1.1,,20
111,10.1.1.1,21,
112,10.1.1.2,10,
112,10.1.1.2,,15
```

Expected output:

```
111,10.1.1.1,21,20
112,10.1.1.2,10,15
```

Comment: 1) can we assume that your file is always sorted? 2) could be there more than **4** fields there?

Comment: exact input like   my input 2018-02-18,111,10.211.16.139,conn-failed ,432
2018-02-18,111,10.211.18.139,conn-failed ,6480
2018-02-19,111,10.211.16.139,conn-failed ,384
2018-02-19,111,10.211.18.139,conn-failed ,5760 require O/P: id, ip,            2018-02-18 ,2018-02-18
111,10.211.16.139,432         ,384
111,10.211.18.139,6480        ,5760

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk -F',+' '{a[$1","$2]=a[$1","$2]","$3} END{for (ip in a)print ip a[ip]}' file | sort
111,10.1.1.1,20,21
112,10.1.1.2,10,15
```

#### How it works

- `-F',+'`

  This tells awk to use any sequence of one or more commas as a field separator.
- `a[$1","$2]=a[$1","$2]","$3`

  For every line, we append the third field to an entry in associative array `a` under the key of the first two field.
- `END{for (ip in a)print ip a[ip]}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, we print out each key of array `a` followed by the value of `a` for that key.
- `sort`

  This optional step sorts the output.  If sorting matters to you, you will likely want to adjust the options to `sort` to get what you want (e.g. lexical vs numerical).

Comment: Hi John , thanks for the reply  it really helpful for but by exact requirement is some thing like below , if u have any idea please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Hi John , thanks for the reply  it really helpful for but by exact requirement is some thing like below , if u have any idea please help me thanks in advance   my input 2018-02-18,111,10.211.16.139,conn-failed ,432
2018-02-18,111,10.211.18.139,conn-failed ,6480
2018-02-19,111,10.211.16.139,conn-failed ,384
2018-02-19,111,10.211.18.139,conn-failed ,5760 require O/P: id, ip,            2018-02-18 ,2018-02-18
111,10.211.16.139,432         ,384
111,10.211.18.139,6480        ,5760